# What does the first bit(i.e. binary 0) mean in UTF-8 encoding standard?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, utf-16, utf

I'm a **PHP Developer** by profession.

Consider below example :

I want to encode the word **"hello"** using **UTF-8** encoding.

So,

Equivalent Code Points of each of the letters of the word **"hello"** are as below :

```
h = 104
e = 101
l = 108
o = 111
```

So, we can say that the list of decimal numbers represent the string **"hello"**:

`104 101 108 108 111`

**UTF-8** encoding will store **"hello"** like this (binary):

```
01101000 01100101 01101100 01101100  01101111
```

If you observe the above binary encoded value closely, you will come to know that every binary equivalent of decimal number has been preceded with the binary bit value `0`.

My question is why this initial `0` has been prefixed to every storable character? What's the purpose of using it in UTF-8 encoding?

What has been done when the same string is encoded using **UTF-16** format?

If is it necessary then can the initial extra character be a bit value `1`?

Does **NUL Byte** mean the binary character `0`?

Comment: The numbers you show are **decimal representations** of codepoints. The actual codepoints are: `h = U+0068 (hex 0x68 dec 104), e = U+0065 (hex 0x65 dec 101), l = U+006C (hex 0x6C dec 108), o = U+006F (hex 0x6F dec 111)`. Codepoints <= U+007F are encoded the same way in UTF-8 and UTF-16, just with UTF-16 extending the 7-bit values to 16 bits. So `hello` is encoded as follows in UTF-16LE: `01101000 00000000 01100101 00000000 01101100 00000000 01101100 00000000 01101111 00000000` and in UTF-16BE: `00000000 01101000 00000000 01100101 00000000 01101100 00000000 01101100 00000000 01101111`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UTF-8 is backwards compatible with ASCII. ASCII uses the values 0 - 127 and has assigned characters to them. That means bytes `0000 0000` through `0111 1111`. UTF-8 keeps that same mapping for those same first 128 characters.

Any character not found in ASCII is encoded in the form of `1xxx xxxx` in UTF-8, i.e. for any non-ASCII character the high bit of every encoded byte is `1`. Those characters are encoded in multiple bytes in UTF-8. The first bits of the first byte in the sequence tell the decoder of how many bytes the character consists of; `110x xxxx` signals that it's a 2-byte character, `1110 xxxx` a 3-byte character and `1111 0xxx` a 4-byte character. Subsequenct bytes in the sequence are in the form `10xx xxxx`.  So, no, you can't just set it to `1` arbitrarily.

There are various extensions to ASCII (e.g. ISO-8859) which set that first bit as well and thereby add another 128 characters of the form `1xxx xxxx`.

There's also 7-bit ASCII which omits the first `0` bit and just uses `000 0000` through `111 1111`.

> Does **NUL Byte** mean the binary character `0`?

It means the bit sequence `0000 0000`, i.e. an all-zero byte with the decimal/hex/octal value `0`.

You may be interested in [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).

Comment: Why does ASCII prepend the extra bit to the binary equivalent of a decimal code point?

Comment: Bytes are 8 bits by typical convention. Standard ASCII just fits to that expectation. Again, 7 bit ASCII explicitly omits the "superfluous" bit, but needs special treatment in return in systems which expect 8 bits per byte by default.

Comment: Are you saying that, as per the convention a byte forms from eight bits and the systems expects the same byte in return which is composed of eight bits? This is the reason behind adding the extra bit at the beginning. Am I getting this right?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: The *extra* `0`s are for human readability. `01101000 01100101 01101100 01101100  01101111` could also be written as `1101000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111`, but that is not as nice to read, since bytes are typically 8 bits in size. Either way, the high bit is still `0` from the computer's perspective. You can't have unassigned bits, a bit is always either 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 encodes Unicode codepoints U+0000 - U+007F (which are the ASCII characters 0-127) using 7 bits. The eighth bit is used to signal when additional bytes are necessary only when encoding Unicode codepoints U+0080 - U+10FFFF.

For example, `è` is codepoint U+00E8, which is encoded in UTF-8 as bytes `0xC3 0xA8` (`11000011 10101000` in binary).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) explains quite well how UTF-8 is encoded.

> Does NUL Byte mean the binary character 0?

Yes.

Comment: @remy A "light editing" :-) Ok... Now my answer is surely more beautiful, but I won't thank you because I think it wasn't really necessary :-)

Comment: it wasnt just about making it look nice. Grammar is important, but so is using correct terminology, too. Unicode is hard enough to grasp without improper names and representations making it more confusing.